# What is C++ for "AND OR"?

Tags: c++, operators

I am writting some conditionall if and I want to have something like

```
if ( /*condition one */) and or ( /* condition two */   )
```

Is there such operator in C++ and how to write it?

So I want something like

```
if((( /* condition A */)&&(/* condition B */ ))|| /* AND OR? */ ((  /* condition C */ )&&(  /* condition D */)))
```

(for figuring out if at least one side of a segment belongs to another segment)

So... there is on "AND OR" IN c++ AND WE SHALL ALWAYS WRITE UGLY CODE DUPLICATION LIKE THIS:

```
if(((( /* condition A */)&&(/* condition B */ ))|| ((   /* condition C */ )&&(  /* condition D */))) || ((( /* condition A */)&&(/* condition B */ )) && (( /* condition C */ )&&(  /* condition D */)))
```

?

Comment: Which do you want, `and` or `or`??

Comment: What do you mean with "and or"?

Comment: What do you mean by "AND OR"?  Could you write a truth table?

Comment: `AND` and `OR` are mutually exclusive operators. Pick one.

Comment: They're mutually exclusive... how could you have both?

Comment: Question is unclear.  What are you trying to accomplish with "and or"?  Can you give us an example?

Comment: I really don't understand all the down-votes (8 in 4 minutes? it's not a competition!). I believe that there is a "good question" here and the complication is merely an artifact of trying to describe something in English. On the other hand, [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086252/can-someone-create-this-for-me-android-app) is worthy of down-votes, sheeple with caution :-)

Comment: I'm forced to assume that the phrase `and/or` is exclusive to American English, since this is a question I've had to answer dozens of times over the years.

Comment: I think the downvotes reflected the 'unclear' part and some have been retracted after user's edit, including my own.

Comment: "So I want something like" That doesn't look anything like the first part. You want `(A&B)|(C&D)`, which involves 4 conditions. Your first part said you wanted `(A and/or B)`, which only involves 2 conditions. Which is it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: He thought C++ `||` or was exclusive or, and by `and/or` he wants an inclusive or.

Comment: Logically `and/or`. That is, he wants the `(inclusive) or`, rather than the `exclusive or`. This is done in C++ using `||`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you mean what I think you mean, then in English it is more commonly written and/or, and what it means is this:

- if A is true and B is false OR
- if A is false and B is true OR
- if A is true and B is true

then the expression is as a whole is true.

If that is what you mean, then the answer is simply `or` or `||`.

The first two cases are typically referred to in programming as an *exclusive or*, or *XOR*: that is, if one is true, and the other is not.

The C++ *or* operator is an inclusive OR, that is, it is true if *one or both* of the operands are true

Answer (score 3):

If you have two conditions, `A` and `B`

```
A | B | A and B | A or B
------------------------
T   T      T        T
T   F      F        T
F   T      F        T
F   F      F        F
```

If A or B is true, A and B is true as well.  Sounds like you just want OR.

Answer (score 2):

and or would simply be or in boolean terms: you can use the double pipe (||) operator for that.

```
if ( /*condition one */) || ( /* condition two */   )
```

Comment: That's `OR`. Where's the `AND`?

Comment: I thought this means only OR... So generally I want to create something like `if((( it->second.first >= start_x)&&(start_x <= it->second.second))|| /* AND OR */ (( it->second.first >= x-1)&&( x-1  <= it->second.second)))`

Comment: @user it *does* mean only `OR`. **Read the comments on your question.**

Comment: @user1040114: You must be thinking of "exclusive or", which means one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `or`. It will evaluate to `true` if even if *both* conditions are true.

In other words, the "or" operation is *inclusive or*, not *exclusive or*. The latter requires that exactly one of the two conditions be true.

We usually use the `||` operator, but `or` also works:

```
if (/* condition one */ || /* condition two */)
```

Answer (score 0):

And takes input with the following output

```
true, true -> true
true, false -> false
false, true -> false
false, false -> false
```

Or takes the input with the following output

```
true, true -> true
true, false -> true
false, true -> true
false, false -> false
```

So if "and or" means that it could be "and" and it could be "or", using a single "or" handles both scenarios if your are only verifying "true" output, as `true, true -> true` (and's only true output) is already contained in the standard `or` output.

If "and or" means that it must be "and" and it must also be "or" using a single "and" handles both scenarios if you are only verifying "true" output, as `true, true -> true` (and's only true output) is already contained in the standard `or` output.

If you are verifying only "false" output, the precedence of which operator to select is inverted depending on the interpretation of the combination.